# WSUS how to get the download status of an update?

Tags: wsus

I found many update waiting to be downloaded from my WSUS server.
For example:

[image]

I found that the daily syncronization is working, but seems that WSUS is still waiting for the download of these update.
How can I check the download status of these udaptes?

Comment: You can right-click on the header and choose additional columns. One of these columns shows the download status (Only have the German version right now, the German column name translates to 'file-status')

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the main dashboard of WSUS server:

[image]